# Flask application return 404 error in python

Tags: python, heroku, flask, error-handling

The application runs perfectly fine on my local machine and I can navigate without errors, but I load into heroku ,I receive a 404 Not Found error for any page that I try to visit, including the index.

Hello/manage.py is the root of my app. Here's what it currently looks like:

```
app = create_app(config.DefaultConfig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

Here's my Hello/hello_sp/_ init _.py:

```
    from flask import Flask 
    from .config import DefaultConfig 
    from .shopify_bp import shopify_bp 
    from .extensions import db 

    __all__ = ['create_app']
DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS = (
    shopify_bp,
)
def create_app(config=None, blueprints=None,third=None):
    """Create Flask app.

    """
    if blueprints is None:
        blueprints = DEFAULT_BLUEPRINTS
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configure_app(app, config)
    configure_blueprints(app, blueprints)
    return app
```

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT manage:app
```

I think everything is set up properly because I'm able to run the app locally without any issues. When I deploy to Heroku, I can see that the site is Up, not Crashed, and I'm not receiving any server errors, just Not Found errors. It's almost as if my routes aren't working or something like that. Here's what I see in my Heroku logs when I try to access my site's homepage

```
2018-10-29T08:51:16.166033+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.95.165.34 - - [29/Oct/2018:08:51:16 +0000] "GET /shopify/?shop=biplecomtesting.myshopify.com HTTP/1.1" 404 233 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"

2018-10-29T08:51:16.167143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/shopify/?shop=biplecomtesting.myshopify.com" host=search-test-bple.herokuapp.com request_id=93249e6d-826e-412a-a82c-594c2ff4542d fwd="223.30.82.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=404 bytes=386 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `manage.py` file has some errors because you just want to create app object, not running it.
Just change your manage.py to this:

```
app = create_app(config.DefaultConfig)
```